# jquery .find('input').each

Tags: jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row that contains inputs down a few descendants. What I am trying to do is capture the values of the children inputs when a button within the row is clicked. I can then use the values further down the line but am not sure how to extract the values properly. Any suggestions on what I have?

```
    <div class="row">   
      <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" value='0' class="form-control" >
</div></div>
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default updateButton">Update</button>
                            </div></div></div></div>

$('.updateButton').on('click', function () {
        var inputs = [];
        $(this).parent('.row').find('input').each(function (i) {
            inputs.push($(this).val());
        });
```

Comment: Where is the button? Otherwise it is hard to tell if your code is correct ...

Comment: edited, it is within the col-md-6 along with the form-groups, but is within a col-sm-offset-2 div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are very close.  You probably want something like this:

```
$('.updateButton').on('click', function() {
    var inputs = [];
    $(this).closest('.row').find('input').each(function() {
        inputs.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: `el===this` inside each

Comment: The difference is my `.closest()` vs. his `.parent()`.  I believe `.parent()` only looks at the matching elements' immediate parent.

Comment: I presumed my issue was with my push(this) rather than el, but am happy to understand that 'this' has it's context change inside the loop. closest solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check this working example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.updateButton', function() {
  var inputs = [];
  // Go up the DOM tree and find the closest .row, then find any input element inside this .row and iterate them
  $(this).closest('.row').find('input').each(function() {
    // For each input, push it's value to inputs array 
    inputs.push($(this).val());
  });
  alert(inputs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">   
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" value='0' class="form-control" >
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default updateButton">Update</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You were close. Use `.parents` instead since `.parent` only travels a single level up the DOM tree.

```
$('.updateButton').on('click', function () {
  var inputs = [];
  $(this).parents('.row').find('input').each(function (i, el) {
    inputs.push($(el).val());
  });
});
```

However, `closest()` is better and is faster. Just wanted to point out what was wrong with your code. Also keep in mind `parents()` will get all the ancestors matching the selector so you might get multiple DOM elements as a result (if you end up having multiple div with `row` as class).

Comment: And as the name said, `parents` can give you more then one element, while `closest` only give you one. Your code may be wrong, if there is a `.row` inside a `.row`, So this is not a answer imo.

Comment: @eisbehr Well I agree with you and that is the reason I added `closest()` at the end. Just wanted to point out whats wrong with his code. Also I think answer does completely depends on what the OP has. What if he has a `.row` div with no input inside current parent (.row) div. Even closest will not work in such case.